# getting Record Type Description

Tags: record-type

What is the best way to get the Record Type Description to display in a page?

```
    public class AccountRecordTypes {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Map<String,String> GetAvailableRecordTypeAccount()
    {
        Map<String,String> recordTypeMap = new Map<String,String>();
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> RT = R.getRecordTypeInfos();

       for( Schema.RecordTypeInfo recordType : RT )
    {
        if(recordType.isAvailable())
        { 
            if(recordType.Name!='Master') {
                recordTypeMap.put(recordType.getRecordTypeId(),recordType.Name);
            }
        }
    }


        }
        return recordTypeMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I understand this correct, you are looking to get the "Description" of the Record Types available for a particular SObject, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but it seems that the getdescribe doesn't have the description

Comment: Are you restricted to use describe apis here?

Comment: no, i'm using the describe but it seems that the description is not available, since what I am going to display to may customize quick action is that an option to choose a record type with description

Comment: Provided an approach as an answer, that should help you here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that using **[RecordTypeInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm#apex_Schema_RecordTypeInfo_methods)**, you cannot actually get the `Description` field. So in that case, you can actually do a SOQL to get the record type details that you need.

Your query should look something as below:

```
SELECT Name, DeveloperName, Description FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Account'
```

And once you get the results, you just construct the return data from your method. Your overall approach should look like this:

```
for(RecordType rec : [SELECT Name, DeveloperName, Description FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Account']) {
    recordTypeMap.put(rec.Name, rec.Description);
}
```

Comment: do you have a sample link for me to follow thank you, yes, that's my option to make through soql

Comment: You are looking for sample for what? How to construct the return data?

Comment: yes, i'm looking for a sample

Comment: I added that in the answer. But you should also look at how to fetch values from SOQL and use that in apex. Start with some trailhead, as [**this one**](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_soql)

Comment: Yes you are correct, apologies, I am having problem with displaying it on the page, i am new to lightning

Comment: You should open that as a separate question which should be more around how to receive a value from server in your component. If you look around, you can find resources on it but if still unable, open a new question. The one here was about how to find the description which has been answered.

Comment: I recently open one but as you said it was duplicate...

Comment: Because you were still looking how to get description. You should provide more details as what are trying to attempt. You should ask rather that now you know how to get the description but how do you display it on the component. Your other question was still referring as you were still trying to get the description in your apex like this one.